# unsure on why i am getting a traceback issue while using shelve

Tags: python, traceback, shelve

any help would be appreciated!
I copied and pasted the code from another application that i made. the issue appears when initiating the login or userregistration functions

```
import shelve
import time 
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init()

FORES = [ Fore.BLACK, Fore.RED, Fore.GREEN, Fore.YELLOW, Fore.BLUE, Fore.MAGENTA, Fore.CYAN, Fore.WHITE ]

BACKS = [ Back.BLACK, Back.RED, Back.GREEN, Back.YELLOW, Back.BLUE, Back.MAGENTA, Back.CYAN, Back.WHITE ]

BRIGHTNESS = [ Style.DIM, Style.NORMAL, Style.BRIGHT ]

item_rarity = {
    'Legendary' : 'YELLOW',
    'Uncommon' : 'GREEN',
    'Common' : 'WHITE',
    'Rare' : 'BLUE',
    'Exotic' : 'RED',
    'Unique' : 'CYAN',
}

Weapons = {'Excalibur': {'rarity': 'Legendary', 'damage': '100',},
          'Dragonblade': {'rarity': 'Exotic', 'damage': '120', },
          'woodensword': {'rarity': 'Common', 'damage': '11', },
          'ironsword': {'rarity': 'Uncommon', 'damage': '39', }}

Armour = {'peasentwear': {'rarity': 'Common', 'defence': '17',},
          'Dragonclothing': {'rarity': 'Exotic', 'defence': '89', },
          'chainmail': {'rarity': 'Common', 'defence': '32', },
          'ironarmour': {'rarity': 'Uncommon', 'defence': '39', }}

Enemies = {'Giant': {'health': '100', 'damage': '10',},
          'Basilisk': {'health': '250', 'damage': '31', },
          'Troll': {'health': '35', 'damage': '8', },
          'Chad': {'health': '50', 'damage': '13', }}

def viewinventory():
    print("work in progress")

def viewloadout():
    username2gold = shelve.open('username2gold')
    username2armour = shelve.open("username2armour")
    username2weapon = shelve.open("username2weapon")

    user_weapon = username2weapon[user_username]
    gold_balance = username2gold[user_username]
    user_armour = username2armour[user_username]

    user_weapon_rarity = Weapons[user_weapon]['rarity']
    user_armour_rarity = Armour[user_armour]['rarity']

    user_armour_rarity_colour = item_rarity[user_armour_rarity]
    user_weapon_rarity_colour = item_rarity[user_weapon_rarity]

    print("Your loadout is as follows:")
    print(f"You currently have {gold_balance} gold")
    print("Your weapon is:")
    print(Fore.BLUE+Back.YELLOW+"Hi My name is Aman Kharwal") 
    


def adventurebegin():
    print("work in progress")

def Adventure_minimum_balance():
    global gold_balance
    if gold_balance >= 100:
        print("You have enough funds to play!")
        gold_balance = gold_balance - 100
        username2gold = shelve.open("username2gold")
        username2gold[user_username] = gold_balance
        print(f"Your new gold balance is {gold_balance}, we hope you enjoy your adventure!")
        adventurebegin()
    else:
        gold_deficit = 100 - gold_balance
        print("You have insufficient gold")
        print(f"You need {gold_deficit} more gold to advance")
        print("You are being returned to the mainmenu")
        print("Come back when you have more gold!")
        mainmenu()

def play():
    print("The adventure continues...")
    request_to_play = input("Would you like to go to the next stage, costing 100 gold? (y/n)")
    while request_to_play != 'y' or 'n':
     request_to_play = input("Invalid input, please try again")
    if request_to_play == 'y':
        Adventure_minimum_balance()
    else:
        print("We are redirecting you back to the mainmenu!")
        time.sleep(1)
        mainmenu()

def mainmenu():
    print("Welcome to the main interface, here you can select what to do next")
    print("1) Continue your Dawsgeon adventure")
    print("2) View your inventory")
    print("3) View your loadout")
    global main_option
    main_option = input("enter the number of what activity you would like to complete:")

def usereg():

    print("Welcome new user to Dawsgeon, here you can register an account!")
    desired_username = str(input("please enter your desired username: "))

    username2password = shelve.open("username2password")
    username2gold = shelve.open("username2gold")
    username2armour = shelve.open("username2armour")
    username2weapon = shelve.open("username2weapon")

    while desired_username in (username2password.keys()):
       print("An adventurer on the Dawsgeon network has already claimed that username")
       desired_username = str(input("please input another username: "))
    else:
       print(f"this username is unique, welcome to Dawsgeon {desired_username}!")
       print("next you need a strong yet memorable password")
       desired_password = str(input("please enter the password you want to use: "))

       print("creating your account... ")
       time.sleep(1)

       username2password[desired_username] = desired_password
       username2gold[desired_username] = 1000
       username2armour[desired_username] = 'peasentwear'
       username2weapon[desired_username] = 'woodensword'

       print(f"account created, your username is {desired_username} and your password is {desired_password}")
       global user_password
       global user_username

       user_username = desired_username
       user_password = desired_password
       global gold_balance
       gold_balance = username2gold[user_password]
    

       username2password.close()  
       username2gold.close()
       mainmenu()
       
def userlogin():
    global user_username
    global user_password
    user_username = str(input("Please enter your username adventurer: "))
    username2password = shelve.open("username2password")

    while user_username not in (username2password.keys()):
     print("The username you have inputted cannot be recognised")
     user_username = str(input("please try again: "))

    print(f"welcome back {user_username}!")
    user_password = str(input("please input your password: "))

    real_password = (username2password[user_username])
    username2gold = shelve.open("username2gold")

    n = 3

    while user_password != real_password and 0 < n:
     n = n - 1
     n_str = str(n)
     print(f"the password you inputted was incorrect, you have {n_str} attempts left")
     user_password = str(input("please retry entering your password: "))

    if n == 0:
     print("You have been locked out")
     quit()
    else:
     print(f"Ah yes, it really is you {user_password}!")
     global gold_balance
     gold_balance = username2gold[user_password]
     username2gold.close()
     username2password.close()
     mainmenu()

print("welcome to Dawsgeon! please select what you would like to do: ")
print("1) Register a new account")
print("2) Login") 

initial_option = int(input("please type your chosen option: "))

if initial_option == 1:
    usereg()
elif initial_option ==2:
    userlogin()
    

if main_option == 1:
    play()
elif main_option == 2:
    viewinventory()
elif main_option == 3:
    viewloadout()
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'ghjsads'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\.py\Dawsgeon\main.py", line 185, in <module>
    usereg()
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\.py\Dawsgeon\main.py", line 136, in usereg
    gold_balance = username2gold[user_password]
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 147, 
in __getitem__
    pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
KeyError: b'ghjsads'
```

Comment: `#may raise KeyError`: well, it did....

Comment: I don't know what `shelve` *is*, so I can't help, but what happens if you just pass the wrong password?  It seems that would likely cause a keyerror

Comment: when you enter the password incorrect it works fine; the user gets free chances then the program quits